# Communication complexity of reconstructing a random bit-string of length $n$

Tags: reference-request, communication-complexity

This seems like a folklore claim but I cannot find any reference to it. If Alice has a bit-string of length $n$ where each entry is independently set to 0 or 1 equiprobably, and Bob's goal is to reconstruct the string with a success probability at least 0.9. What is the simplest way to show that the randomized communication complexity (multiple rounds are allowed) is $\Omega(n)$?

One can use an overkilled proof: such a protocol will lead to a protocol for Disjointness and we know that Disjointness requires $\Omega(n)$ bits of communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose Alice always sends exactly $k$ bits to Bob during the protocol.  On average, how many possible candidates for her $n$-bit string are consistent with the communication transcript?  What does that tell you about the probability that Bob guesses which one of those candidates is the correct one?

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot!